# freemarker how to stop rendering

Tags: rendering, freemarker

I have a freemarker template that shows a list of items. When the variable containing the list is empty, I would like to output an empty message and stop the rendering.
eg.

```
<#if someList?has_content == false>
<span>The list is empty</span>
<#stop/>
</#if>
```

Is there a directive that I can use rather than <#stop>.  This directive ends up putting an error message in the output page.  If there is no simpler solution, I can always fall back to

`<#if><#else></#if>`

Answer (score 1):

There's no such directive. (`#stop` is for terminating due to error, as you have experienced.)

The use case you refer to reminds me of `<#list someList!>...<#items as ...>...</#items>...<#else>...</#list>` though. Maybe you can use that construct.

Comment: Thanks. This will do too.