# How to end FreeMarker processing prematurely in normal way?

Tags: freemarker

I'd like to exit early from processing a FreeMarker template (to reduce indentation compared to wrapping a lot of code in a conditional). Like:

```
<#if !precondition><#-- End processing --></#if>

<#-- Do something if precondition met -->
```

I've been reading through the [docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_stop.html) for `<#stop>` which say

> This must not be used for ending template processing in normal situations!

but unfortunately the docs forget to say what *is* the way to end template processing in normal situations.

Comment: Ok, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39044438/1127485) which comes close enough to a duplicate. Unfortunately the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045323/1127485) is "There's no such directive".

Comment: Basically yes, see my own link above (and my own vote to close). I was just hoping that by now there would be a way.